# How to determine the parameters of a linearized model when the line has negative slope and intercept?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

I have the following data:

| Sample | $t$ | $q_t$ | $\ln\left(q_e-q_t\right)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0.00 | 0.31 |
| A | 60 | 0.97 | -0.92 |
| A | 90 | 1.30 | -2.71 |
| A | 120 | 1.33 | -3.40 |
| A | 180 | 1.28 | -2.48 |
| A | 240 | 1.35 | -4.09 |
| A | $q_e=$ | 1.37 |  |
| B | 0 | 0.00 | 0.64 |
| B | 60 | 1.12 | -0.24 |
| B | 90 | 1.77 | -2.01 |
| B | 120 | 1.83 | -2.71 |
| B | 180 | 1.88 | -4.09 |
| B | 240 | 1.80 | -2.30 |
| B | $q_e=$ | 1.90 |  |

The data, from both sample A and sample B, were adjusted to the following model in its linearized form, to determine the value of the parameters $k$ and $q_e$:
$$\ln\left(q_e-q_t\right)=\ln q_e-kt \rightarrow \rm linearized\ form$$
$$q_t=q_e\left[1-\exp\left(-kt\right)\right]\rightarrow \rm original\ model$$
I did the regressions and these are the results:
[image]

According to my mathematical knowledge, a straight line is defined by the equation $y = b+mx$. With that the calculation of the parameters $k$ and $q_e$ would be:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Straight line | $y$ | $=$ | $b$ | $+$ | $m$ | $x$ |
| Model | $\ln\left(q_e-q_t\right)$ | $=$ | $\ln q_e$ | $-$ | $k$ | $t$ |

- $q_e=e^{\rm intercept}=\exp(\rm intercept)$
- $k=-\rm slope$

Following this procedure, I estimated the values of $k$ and $q_e$ for each sample and then I plotted it in a non-linear form:

| Sample | $k$ | $q_e$ | Plotted function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.02 | 0.73 | $q_t=0.73\left[1-\exp(-0.02t)\right]$ |
| B | 0.02 | 1.02 | $q_t=1.02\left[1-\exp(-0.02t)\right]$ |

[image]

Looking at the graph, I believe that I made a mistake in one of my procedures and I would like your help, because I believe that the non-linear curves should be closer to the points.